# Cursor jumping with curses.h library

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, semaphore

I have a project using curses and sockets to make a talking program.  Basically the main thread starts up two threads to manage two halves of the screen and another thread to manage the sending/receiving through the network.  The code seems very clean, but for some reason the cursor jumps around the screen seemingly at random at times.  Usually around three rows in it will start jumping all over the place.  I have no mv___() functions from curses so I am confused as to why the cursor is going rogue on me.

Here is the function called by the two threads to manage the two sides of the screen.  Any ideas as to what might cause this?

```
void *display(int sub)
{
    int bufSize = 10;
    char* buf = (char*)calloc(bufSize, sizeof(char));

    while(read(displayPipe[sub][0], buf, 1) > 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&displaySem);

        waddch(subWin[sub], buf[0]);
        wrefresh(subWin[sub]);

        sem_post(&displaySem);
    }

    free(buf);

    return NULL;
```

}

Here is the function which is reading from the socket

```
void *netToPipe()
{       
    int bufSize = 10;
    char* buf = (char*)calloc(bufSize, sizeof(char));

    // read from talkfd
    while(read(talkfd, buf, 1) != EOF)
    {
        // print to the bottom of the screen
        if(write(displayPipe[1][1], buf, 1) < 0)
            (void)printf("Error writing to talkfd\n");
    }

    free(buf);

    return NULL;
}
```

And here is the end of main() which is reading from keyboard and writing to the bottom of the screen (through the pipe) and to the socket.

```
while(1)
    {
        // get a key from the subwindow
        key = wgetch(subWin[0]);        

        // we are connected to a client
        if(talkfd > 0)  
        {
            // send across network
            write(talkfd, &key, 1);
            // copy to upper portion of the screen
            write(displayPipe[0][1], &key, 1);
        }
        // we are just talking to self
        else
        {
            // send to bottom of screen
            write(displayPipe[1][1], &key, 1);
            // send to top of screen
            write(displayPipe[0][1], &key, 1);  
        }
        refresh();

    }
```

Comment: Are you using the [threading-aware version of `ncurses`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/use_screen)?

Comment: @sarnold I am just including the curses.h header that is installed on our linux machines here.  I am not sure or aware of threading-aware versions of curses.

Comment: Note that [C99 introduced Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) -- if you're alright  with requiring C99 for your project you could replace the `calloc()` with: `char buf[bufSize];`.

Comment: Hrm; I didn't find any `ncursest` thread-aware variants on http://packages.ubuntu.com or http://packages.debian.org or http://software.opensuse.org/121/en-- makes me wonder if any distributions distribute the thread-aware variant?

Comment: My professor gave us a lot of the code to start out with.  The curses.h library was already included so I am not sure that a thread-aware variant would fix the problem.  I (and my professor) very well could be wrong though.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a multi-threaded program and ncurses together? That just sounds like trouble. Either doing everything in a single process or go with two processes and two terminals... multithreaded terminal code just sounds so wrong.

Comment: @sarnold Unfortunately yes. The project was supposed to make us learn how to use multiple threads and coordinate them correctly using semaphores. It's not at all idea. Even he had a ton of trouble getting my program where it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the enormous pile of constraints that have been placed on your program, I think the absolute *best* you can do is confine *all* `curses` functions to a single thread -- all input, all output, all re-drawing, etc. Keep the IO threads dedicated to *only* network IO, never any `curses`-based console IO. Because stock curses on the platforms I cared to inspect do not support multi-threaded operation, there's still no guarantees that you can write a bug-free program in this manner, but it is your best shot.

A similar, and far more Unix-ish approach, would be to use multiple *processes* instead of threads. That way, the protected memory wouldn't let the different processes accidentally scribble over `curses` global or static storage and you have a better chance of writing bug-free software.

Of course, the *most* Unix-ish approach would use [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) to multiplex all the IO in one thread and one process. (But this might also have trouble working with `curses`. It's amazing software that has its roots planted three decades ago...)

Comment: The program ultimately still jumps.  I could only guess that it has to do with the multi-threading aspect of this.  However part of the reason the jumping was so bad was because I was remote connecting via ssh.  Logging directly into the system help with some of the jumping issues.

Comment: Hrm; if you had trouble with the `ssh` but local works fine, I wonder if the terminfo database on the host machine, your `TERM` environment variable, and the terminal on the client machine were all matching? Mis-matched terminal information can lead to .. non-optimal .. use of terminal drawing.